# Illustrator save SVG text issue

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

Illustrator save SVG text issue

I have an adobe illustrator file that contains many objects polygon, rec and text when i save the file as SVG it render the text as path i want to render the text as text.

Any help please to render the text with the  tag.

Comment: you should post your code it will be helping to recognize your quesiton

Comment: It's possible that whoever created your SVG file converted all the text to paths.  If that is the case, then there is no easy way to reverse the process.  You would need to delete all the converted text and recreate them all again as normal text objects.